# How to apply a square mesh to every face of another object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, instances

I'm, sure there's a feature for this, but I don't know the name or how to search for it. basically I want to recreate the ceiling of the pantheon:
[image]

I was thinking I could make a half-sphere, and then on another object I make a square stepped-pyramid shape, and then somehow "apply" that shape to selected faces of the sphere to take into account the narrowing of the squares... Any suggestions for a workflow like this?
[image]

Comment: Tissue addon is made for that. It is included in Blender, just activate it. You'll find it in the tools, right of the 3d view. Then tessellate onto the half sphere (active object) with the wall part object (selected).

Comment: a link to the documentation https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/tissue.html